# Display inline radio buttons with spacing to full width of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form on my page, but the radio buttons are aligned to the left. I would like them to be spaced so they span the full width of the containing div. Here is the current code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend class="col-form-label required">Question</legend>
  <div id="question">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_0" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="1">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_0">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_28_1" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="2">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_1">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_1" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="3">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_2">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_3" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="4">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_3">4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_4" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="5">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_4">5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_5" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="6">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_5">6</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_6" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="7">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_6">7</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_7" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="8">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_7">8</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_8" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="9">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_8">9</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="question_9" name="question[1]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="10">
      <label class="form-check-label required" for="question_9">10</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the CSS you are using to try to achieve this, so we can help you figure out why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bootstrap Flex Utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/) readily provides the classes needed for the spacing. You can achieve this layout just by adding `d-flex` & `justify-content-between` to your questions container

```
<div id="question" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
   ...
</div>
```